# Is there a way to check if a host is up?

Tags: php, ping, fsockopen

I'm trying to do this in PHP. I need to check if a specified host is "up"

I thought of pinging the specified host (though I'm not sure how I would, since that would require root. --help here?)

I also though of using `fsockopen()` to try to connect on a specified port, but that would fail too, if the host wasn't listening for connections on that port.

Additionally, some hosts block ping requests, so how might I get around this? This part isn't a necessity, though, so don't worry about this too much. I realize this one might get tricky.

Comment: What service do you want to check up-ness for?

Comment: The host in general. No specific service. Basically if the host is online. Some of the hosts don't have a webserver or anything, so this will be difficult.

Answer (score 5):

I typically do a simple cURL for a public page and see if it returns a 200. If you get a 500, 404, or anything besides a 200 response you know something fishy is up.

Comment: thats my way too, addionitally its useful to just use a HEAD request. Much faster and enough information included.

Comment: Whomever -1'ed this answer should have explained why it's incorrect or lacking.

Comment: Did not dv but ... some hosts have a specific mission, which may or may not be http'ish. Even with an http server, ports are entirely up to the server admin.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that there is no good, universal way to do this. Ping is about as close as you can get (almost all hosts will respond to that), but as you observed, in PHP that usually requires root access to use the low port.

Does your host allow you to execute system calls, so you could run the ping command at the OS level and then parse the results? This is probably your best bet.

```
$result = exec("ping -c 2 google.com");
```

If a host is blocking a ping request, you could do a more general portscan to look for other open ports (but this is pretty rude, don't do it to hosts who haven't given you specific permission). [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) is a good tool for doing this. It uses quite a few tricks to figure out if a host is up and what services may or may not be running. Be careful though, as some shared hosting providers will terminate your account for "hacking activity" if you install and use Nmap, especially against hosts you do not control or have permission to probe.

Beyond that, if you are on the same unswitched ethernet layer as another host (if you happen to be on the same open WiFi network, for example), an ethernet adaptor in promiscuous mode can sniff traffic to and from a host even if it does not respond directly to you.

Comment: Would that exec() not require root?

Comment: That exec would not usually require root. Ping is generally allowed for regular users, and `exec` has never required root in PHP. The `exec` will run with the same permissions as whichever user PHP is running under.

Comment: Didn't let me. `ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Your host is pretty restrictive then. Most hosts (including most shared hosts) allow ping. Have you considered finding a better host for your needs? Yours clearly is configured to make what you want to do extremely difficult.

Comment: Actually, I'm using a dedicated server that I have root access to.

Comment: Then configure your server to allow this... Allowing low ports for a specific application is pretty easy, and definitely shouldn't require your application itself to have root permissions.

Comment: Some hosts (mine do) and some networks (mine do) block ICMP packets.  So a `failed` ping will only tell you that ping failed, and no certainty about the target host's status.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cURL

```
$url = 'yoururl';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if (200==$retcode) {
    // All's well
} else {
    // not so much
}
```

Comment: And if that host isn't running a webserver? Or it's not on port 80?

Comment: If it's not running, the domain doesn't exist, or it's not on port 80 then the $retcode will return int(0).  If you need to check other ports then add a port number.  We've been using this solution in a production environment for a long time withtout any problems.

Comment: I'm using Mikrotik API with [this PHP API client](https://github.com/BenMenking/routeros-api), they use socket to call MT API at port 8728. If I change URL in your code to start with `tcp://`, `sockets://`, `sockets5://`. It seems they are all return int `0` even the domain or ip is correct. Or if I removed protocol then it seems to be waiting forever.

Answer (score 0):

For the host to be monitored at all, at least one port must be open. Is the host a web server? If so you could just open a connection to port 80, as long as it's opened successfully then at least some part of the host is working.

A better solution would be to have a script that is web accessible to just your monitor, and then you could open a connection to that, and that script would return various bits of system info.

EDIT--

How thorough do you want this test to be?
[server on] -> [apache running] -> [web application working]
Are all different levels of working. Just showing apache is returning something does at least show the server is on, but not that your web app is running. 
(I realise that you may not be running anything like this but I hope it's a useful example)

EDIT--

Would it be worth installing a lightweight http server (I mean very light weight) just for monitoring?

Failing that could you install something on the hosts that phoned home every so often to show they are up?

Answer (score -1):

I used `gethostbyname($hostname)`.

The function gives you the IP if the host is up, or the input hostname if it couldn't find the IP.

```
if ($hostname !== gethostbyname($hostname)) {
    //Host is up
}
```

Comment: `hetHostByName` is actually a DNS query, and will say nothing about 'being up'.  It may tell you that your DNS resolution process knows (or not) the hostname.

Comment: Good point. For my use case (trying to see if the docker container can access another docker container), resolving the DNS and host being "up" is the same thing. But, I can see how this is not applicable for the original question :\