# How to add email function to this php checking script?

Tags: php, email, ip, port

How to add email function to send if the port isnt responding (false) to this script below ?

```
<?php

function test_port($host,$port=80,$timeout=6)
{
        $fsock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
        if ( ! $fsock )
        {
                return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
                return TRUE;
        }
}

/* check our website http://www.example.com is up and running (port 80) and timeout after 20 seconds */
$ok = test_port('IP/website',80,20);

?>
```

Comment: Please read the FAQ again: http://stackoverflow.com/faq - Also search for your question before asking it. I write this especially because your "question" in it's current form is none. By searching first you might find the information you're looking for anyway.

Comment: -1 from me: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be replacing `return FALSE;` with an appropriate call to the [PHP `mail` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

EDIT: this solves the `mail()` poblem, but note that fsockopen **might not be the right way to detect if a host is up**. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686213/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-host-is-up) could be a good starting point.

Comment: so, like that ? http://pastebin.com/iMN3HaDr

Comment: No, use `mail()` like [this](http://codepad.org/ubBUhu2J). Also, consider replacing lines 6-12 with something like `return !!$fsock` or anything else directly casting to boolean values.

Comment: used your script but when the server isnt responding to the port it says: 


Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ip ... connection refused.

Comment: The `mail()` call is working (test it separately), your problem now is that `fsockopen()` could not be the right way to find if the host is up. I think you may ignore the warning.

Comment: ohh, actually it works. it's sending email and giving this error. this should be normal because the port is off and thats why it should give this error, am I right ?? also, how to implement !!$fsock correctly ?

Comment: It works and it's sending email. But just I receive this error when I execute the script and if the server is offline and not responding to the port. 

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to IP:12000 (Connection refused) in /home/public_html/monitor.php on line 5

That should be normal, right ? Since the server isnt responding and its basically is offline.

Comment: You should be right, although I can't confirm that.

Comment: or it should return only false not this error ?

Comment: No. I meant its working correctly but just thought if this error is normal or if it can cause something alwful .. if you think that i can leave it like that .. it will still work correctly. can i leave it like that ?

Comment: I repeat, I am quite sure that you can ignore that, but I have no source to confirm such a statement.

Comment: yeah, it works correctly. I think this error won't do something bad .. so its safe to ignore it because actually it works. Thank you a lot. will +rep

Comment: Done. Didn't know that I should do it. Thank you once again.